# How generate iOS Development Certificate using https://developer.apple.com?

Tags: ios, macos, ionic-framework, phonegap

My main goal is configure an iOS development environment without mac.

After a success account creation in https://developer.apple.com 
and according this guides :

https://web.archive.org/web/20150303180446/http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/detailed_guide_for_setting_up_building_ios_apps_without_a_mac

https://gist.github.com/jcward/d08b33fc3e6c5f90c18437956e5ccc35

https://blog.testproject.io/2018/06/11/ios-test-windows-without-mac/

I need to upload the Certificate Signing Request .csr (created with openssl) to the Apple Developer Site :

http://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/certificates/team/index.action

or

https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/create

The problem is that after accessing any of these urls, I'm redirected to

https://developer.apple.com/account/#/welcome

Also I have searched "certificate" option in this page **developer.apple.com** with no success.

I should see **certificate** option in **Program Resources** section :

https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1IMgO5n0g61TzKr2bCXvG9mFOfJiHosl7

But I see only **Additional Resources** :

https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1esVMWXvkuHRm1JzK_uYyxOgLDS5DsMPy

So my questions are :

- Do I need to pay, have a mac or iphone to enable this certificate option in https://developer.apple.com ?
- Is there another option to generate the **iOS Development Certificate** .cer file without mac/iphone ?

Comment: Are you using VM?

Comment: Virtual Machine?... No. I'm using a linux machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a paid member of the Apple Developer Program to access the certificate-related pages of the developer website. You can either pay for your account, or join a team that has paid for membership in the program.

After you've become a paid member, the account landing page will look like this:

[image]

[You can enroll here](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/), and the price is USD 99 per year at the time of writing.

Comment: Thanks @valdimar. I will try to validate your info with a friend who has already enrolled or I will have to pay :s